# when open R I got an error: '\r' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""c:\r" how can I solve it

Tags: r, startup

When I open R got an error like this, and I don't know how to solve it.

I still have this error when I reinstall both R and Rstudio.
I can use R as normal after the error except installing source package from GitHub using `devtools::install_git()`, it will have the same error as before.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please spend some time learning [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions here on SO, and then provide a [minimal reproducible example/attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). You might also want to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Does it work after that initial error? Is the error thrown if starting with `R --vanilla`. Did you try reinstalling?

Comment: @user20650 thanks for your answer, it still have this error when I reinstall both R and Rstudio, and I can use R as normal except installing source package in GitHub using devtools::install_git(), it will have the same error as before.

Comment: try erasing any `.RData` file in your working directory or disabling "restore workspace on startup" in your RStudio options

Comment: @user20650@Ben Bolker Thanks both of you, this error disappears when I erasing.RData file.But I still don't understand how this error happened.

Comment: R works with forward strokes (`/`) for filepaths and backslashes (`\ `) to be able to write special characters (e.g., `"\."` to indicate a dot in `grep()`). Maybe that's where your error comes from.

Comment: Something in your startup code likely tried to source a file that contained a string entered with unescaped backslashes.